# Accessing content values in Polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer

After finishing Polymer's post-card/post-list tutorial, I am making a simple quiz app based off these elements. My kanji-list is a collection of 5 kanji-cards:

```
<div layout vertical center>
    <template repeat="{{k in kanjiarray}}"><kanji-card>
    <h1>{{k.japan}}</h1>
    <h2>{{k.eigo}}</h2>
    </kanji-card></template>
</div>
```

The meat of the kanji-card element looks like this:

```
  <content select="h1"></content>
  <content select="img"><img src="{{image}}"></content>
  <content select="h2"></content>

</div>
<div class="card-body">
<p>Can you identify this?</p> <br/>
    <label for="nameInput">Answer:</label>
<input id="answerInput" value="{{answer}}"
       placeholder="Enter answer...">
        <img id="go" on-click="{{buttonClick}}" src="{{go}}">
```

My question is, how do I access the contents of the h2 element? I want to write a short Javascript function that will check the user's input against the answer in h2. I have been browsing for a while and can't find a solution that works for me, if anybody can help me that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overall, I'd probably  go with Mohammad's answer. The post-card in the tutorial is designed to show how composition works in shadow DOM, but it's only one possible way to design this component. So I'm going to offer two possible approaches to your problem, based on where you want the logic to live: in the parent element or the card element.

#### First approach: logic in the parent

If you want the parent (kanji-list) element to manage the logic, you can follow the model of the tutorial, and have the card simply fire an event when the user chooses an answer. You can see how the tutorial handles such an event here:

https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-tutorial/blob/master/finished/post-list.html#L35

In the event handler, the value you're looking for (the value that's plugged into the H2) would be something like `sender.templateInstance.model.k.eigo`.

#### Second approach: logic in the card element

If you want the kanji-card to manage the logic, you can use data binding to populate the data into the card. In other words, have an element something like this:

```
<polymer-element name="kanji-card" attributes="kanji">
  <template>
     <h1 id="nihongo">{{kanji.japan}}</h1>
     <img src="{{kanji.image}}">
     <h2 id="eigo">{{kanji.eigo}}</h2>

     ... (rest as before)
enter code here
```

If you write your element this way (note the ID on the H2), you can retrieve the answer using automatic node finding:

```
var answer = this.$.eigo.textContent
```

#### Lastly: the answer to the question you asked

Finally, the literal answer to your question: if you want to retrieve the contents of the H2, it's easier than it looks. In your existing code, the H2 is added as a regular child of the kanji-card, so you can use `querySelector` to get the element. From your `buttonClick` method, that would look like:

```
var answer = this.querySelector('h2').textContent;
```

Comment: Thanks, I went for your second suggestion and it worked exactly as I wanted it to and helped me better understand how attributes work, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to create a `kanji` attribute in your `kanji-card` element, that's why data binding exists, you dont have to deal with DOM to get the data.

So:

```
<polymer-element name="kanji-card" attributes="kangi">
<template>
<!-- card template goes here -->
</template>
<script>
Polymer({
   created: function() {
       kangi = {};
   }
});
</script>
</polymer-element>
```

Then you can use it:

```
<div layout vertical center>
    <template repeat="{{k in kanjiarray}}">
    <kanji-card kanji="{{k}}">
    <h1>{{k.japan}}</h1>
    <h2>{{k.eigo}}</h2>
    </kanji-card></template>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Mohammad, I kind of understand a little bit. Yours and Dude's tips were incredibly helpful.